# "no match for call" error using boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost-bind

I'm still new to boost::bind, and now porting a program that was written 2 yrs ago in 2009, seeing the compile error below. Any idea to workaround would be appreciated.

Extracted cpp file:

```
class ClassA {
private:
    cNamespace::Bounds bounds_msg_;

    void boundsHandler(const PublisherPtr& p) { 
        p->publish(bounds_msg_);
    }

    void funcA() {
        node_->advertise<cNamespace::Bounds>("bounds", 10,
              boost::bind(&ClassA::boundsHandler, this, _1));  // <---- Line 445
    }
};
```

Error upon CMake:

```
/home/userA/ClassA.cpp:445:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, ClassA, const PublisherPtr&>) (ClassA*&, const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher&)’
```

Environment: Ubuntu 10.10, g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5

Might not be necessary but API reference of function `advertise` is [here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a2d81fe5562417931bd7634490c364473), or:

```
template<class M >
Publisher   advertise (const std::string &topic, 
                       uint32_t queue_size, 
                       const SubscriberStatusCallback &connect_cb, 
                       const SubscriberStatusCallback &disconnect_cb=SubscriberStatusCallback(),
                       const VoidConstPtr &tracked_object=VoidConstPtr(), 
                       bool latch=false)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the function object that is produced by `boost::bind` is called with a different type than the function you bound.

i.e. it's called with `const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher&` argument, instead of the expected `const PublisherPtr& p`.

Assuming `SubscriberStatusCallback` is a `boost::function`, you should make sure its argument matches the one you bound.